# how to add dynamic framework in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, xcode12, google-cast-sdk

I tried to add dynamic framework "GoogleCast.framework" to Xcode project

and then I archived but it's not working..

I tried below

1. add in my project to Frameworks Folder
2. checked "Embed & Sign"
3. and then archive

Actually, I don't know how to add dynamic framework.. so I have too much question..

do I set "Header Search Paths" ?

this is error code during archive
`Code signing "GoogleCast.framework" failed.`

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

**Step1:** Go to project General tab

**Step2:** Go to Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded content

**Step3:** In front of GoogleCast.framework do Embed without signing

Comment: Thank you for answer!! so I tried
but... this way was failed..
I looked below message

Unsupported Architectures. The executable for MyProject.app/Frameworks/GoogleCast.framework contains unsupported architectures '[i386, x86_64]'. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90087 for id 095e7423-d551-4063-98d3-9f28dd7c0842

Comment: yes the above issue has solved but you have to fix this issue you are getting.

Comment: Thank you~
if I resolve problem, will add comment! you can look forward to it